# Remove a drop down item if it is selected

Tags: php, jquery, kohana

I have multiple instances of select drop downs on a form, eight to be exact. If I select a number on the first select drop down I want to hide the selected number from the second select drop down up to eighth.

For the purpose of this I will only show two of the eight select drop downs.

View Code -

Select drop down one -

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo Form::label('test_id', 'Test', array('class' => 'col-xs-3 control-label')) ?>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select name="test_id" id="test_id" class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Select...">
            <option value=""></option>                                       
            <?php foreach (ORM::factory('Test')->order_by('id')->find_all() as $row) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->id ?>" 
            <?php if ($b->id == $row->id) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>
            <?php echo $row->id ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Select drop down two-

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo Form::label('test_id', 'Test', array('class' => 'col-xs-3 control-label')) ?>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select name="test_id" id="test_id" class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Select...">
            <option value=""></option>                                       
            <?php foreach (ORM::factory('Test')->order_by('id')->find_all() as $row) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->id ?>" 
            <?php if ($b->id == $row->id) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>
            <?php echo $row->id ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code -

```
var $selects = $('select');
$('select').change(function () {
    $('option:hidden', $selects).each(function () {
        var self = this,
            toShow = true;
        $selects.not($(this).parent()).each(function () {
            if (self.value == this.value) toShow = false;
        })
        if (toShow) $(this).show();
    });
    if (this.value != "") //to keep default option available
      $selects.not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').hide();
});
```

This does not work in the slightest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: can you show the rendered html for the selects instead of the php.  Also the two php snippets you have posted look to be exactly the same - ids should be unique if this is correct

Comment: Is the jQuery code in $(document).ready()?

Comment: Yes it is $(document).ready() Vlad

Comment: It seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/10nwqwck/1/. I also tried adding duplicate IDs to see if that breaks it, and it works.

Comment: Hold on, are you using select2 for the selects?

Comment: Yes I am using select2 for the selects Vlad

Comment: Then try calling .select2() on the selects after hiding the options. I'm not sure if it'll work with hidden options. Otherwise you'll have to remove the option completely. The selects need to be "re-rendered" after any change on it's options.

Comment: How would that look ? - calling .select2() on the selects after hiding the options

Comment: I tested it out and it doesn't work with hidden options, however you can disable the options instead. I added an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work with select2 and hidden options. You can work around this by disabling the options and a bit of CSS to hide them. See below:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selects = $('select');
    $selects.select2();
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('option:hidden', $selects).each(function () {
            var self = this,
                toShow = true;
            $selects.not($(this).parent()).each(function () {
                if (self.value == this.value) toShow = false;
            })
            if (toShow) {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
                $(this).parent().select2();
            }
        });
        if (this.value != "") {
            $selects.not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $selects.select2();
        }
    });
})
```

CSS

```
.select2-results .select2-disabled {
    display:none;
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/10nwqwck/4/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work :

```
$(".select").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    // to hide every option that have the selected value
    $("option").filter(function() {    
        return $(this).val() == value;  
    }).hide();

    // to show the option currently selected in the current list
    $(this).find("option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == value)
        {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers Vlad, that worked mate.

To make the jQuery more optimized, this was done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $selects = $('select');
  $selects.select2();
  $('select').change(function () {
     $('option:hidden', $selects).each(function () {
        var self = this,
                toShow = true;
        $selects.not($(this).parent()).each(function () {
           if (self.value == this.value) toShow = false;
        })
        if (toShow) {
           $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     });
     if (this.value != "") {
        $selects.not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
  });
})
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Select_id").blur(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert($("#Select_id").val() == value);
        // to hide every option that have the selected value
        if ($("#Select_id").val() == value) {
            $("#Option_id"+value).hide();
        }
    });
```

Try this
you can remove the selected item from the drop doen like this simply. dropdown id is 'Select_id' and selected option id need to be 'Option_id'. if not equel both then selected option will be remove

Comment: It is helpful for readers to have some explanation along with an answer so that they might understand why it works.